# CSS не подгружается в iframe в Internet Explorer

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

iframe в Internet Explorer (Последняя версия) не в состоянии загрузить мой css, в то время как Chrome, Safari, Firefox не испытывает никаких затруднений в этом.

Мои файлы стиля подключены к iframe странице, используя следующий код HTML:

```html
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/webapp/load-css/BNP/default/css/default.css?loc=1" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/webapp/load-css/css/default.css?loc=4" />
```

вот полный заголовок HTML внутри iframe:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" class="flexNav-no-touch">
 <head>
  <meta name="copyright" content="Atos" />
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="content-script-type" content="text/javascript" />
  <meta http-equiv="expires" content="0" />
  <meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />
  <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache, must-revalidate" />
  <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
  <meta name="format-detection" content="email=no" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0; user-scalable=1;" /> 
  <title>Capture card details page</title> 
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/webapp/load-css/BNP/default/css/default.css?loc=1" />
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/webapp/load-css/css/default.css?loc=4" />
```

Comment: последняя версия IE это EDGE ?